# C pointer declaration for pointing to a row of 2-d array

Tags: c

I came across this declaration in KN King's book on Page 269

```
int a[ROWS][COLS], (*p)[COLS];

p = &a[0];
```

`p` now points to the first row of 2-d array. I  understand why `a[0]` points to first row of 2-d array. But I do not understand the syntax for declaring `p`. What does that mean and how do I remember it?

What are the parens around `*p` doing ? `(*p)` what does this syntax mean in terms of operator precedence?

Comment: simple its a pointer to an array of `cols` elements of type int. rip it out and analyze like *p(a pointer) then an array declaration `(*p)[]` then each element type `int`. the array size is `cols`. now since edit parn arount p guards it to be declared as pointer to somethin rather than array of int pointers.

Comment: The parentheses are because otherwise the `[]` binds before the `*`.  `int *p[COLS]` is an array of pointers, `int (*p)[COLS]` is a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`> "But I do not understand the syntax for declaring p"`

So `p` is declared as:

```
int (*p)[COLS];
```

It's a pointer to an array of `int`s which is `COLS` in size.

`> "What does that mean and how do I remember it?"`

Here's how you can tell, [use the spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) and start by working in the `()`s:

```
    ( p)                    p 
    (*p)                    p is a pointer
    (*p)[    ]              p is a pointer to an array
int (*p)[    ]              p is a pointer to an array of ints
int (*p)[COLS]              p is a pointer to an array of ints of size COLS
```

Of course you could always [cheat to get the answer too](http://cdecl.org/):

[image]

`> "what does this syntax mean in terms of operator precedence?"`

In the [C Language, `[]` has precedence over the unary  `*`](http://www.swansontec.com/sopc.html), that means you need the `()` in order for `p` to be a pointer to an array of `int`s, instead of an array of pointers to `int`s.

Answer (score 2):

Both postfix `[]` and `()` operators have higher precedence than the unary `*` operator, so they bind first.  IOW, `T *p[N]` is interpreted as `T *(p[N])`; `p` is an array of pointers to `T`.  In order to declare a *pointer to an array* (or pointer to a function), you have to use parentheses to force the `*` operator to bind before the `[]`:

```
T *p[N];     // p is an array of pointer to T
T (*p)[N];   // p is a pointer to an array of T

T *f();      // f is a function returning pointer to T
T (*f)();    // f is a pointer to a function returning T
```

Answer (score 2):

> I understand why a[0] points to first row of 2-d array

This is already inaccurate. In value context, `a[0]` does not really point "to the first row of 2D array". `a[0]` actually points to the *first element* of the first row of 2D array. In other words, in value context `a[0]` is a pointer to `a[0][0]`. The type of `a[0]` decays to `int *`, as you probably know. And `sizeof *a[0]` is equal to `sizeof(int)`. So, it doesn't really point to the entire row. It points to a lone `int` object.

Now, if you really want to point to the first row of a 2D array, i.e. point to the *entire* row, you need `&a[0]`. That will give you a pointer of type `int (*)[COLS]`. Note that `sizeof *&a[0]` is equal to `sizeof (int[COLS])`, so it is truly a pointer to the first row of a 2D array. This is what you see in your example.

Note that numerically `a[0]` and `&a[0]` (as pointers in value context) are the same, since they are pointing to the same spot in linear memory. However, type-wise `&a[0]` points to the entire row, while `a[0]` points to a single element.

Answer (score 1):

ignore the comma and re-write as:

```
int a[ROWS][COLS];
int (*p)[COLS];

p = &a[0];
```

`p` is a pointer to an array of ints `COLS` big
the declaration doesn't allocate that much memory, but it does allow some bounds checking. The memory for the array was allocated in the declaration of:
 `a` => `int a[ROWS][COLS];`

Comment: It is the first time I see a pointer declared like that. So, if p is incremented by 1 it will now be pointing to the first element of the second row?

Comment: @CarlNorum Can you describe the syntax to me or point me to a reference please?

Comment: @CarlNorum Thanks!  Learned something new today!  =)

Comment: It's a normal C pointer-to-array.  Check out a beginner book or tutorial, I guess?  You may find the `cdecl` tool helpful.